# Flutter web error pluginConstants['isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled'] != null

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

I have a code like below, initially I used this code for iOS and Android applications, now I want the application to run on the web, but when I run I get this error

> runZonedGuarded: Caught error in my root zone.
> pluginConstants['isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled'] != null is not true

someone suggested using kisweb, I've used it, but I still get the same error, please help, here's my code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if(!kIsWeb) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }

  runZonedGuarded(() async {
    if (kDebugMode) {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
    }else{
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    }
    runApp(App(
      authenticationRepository: AuthenticationRepository(),
      userRepository: UserRepository(),
    ));
  }, (error, stackTrace) async {
    print('runZonedGuarded: Caught error in my root zone. $error');
  });
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>


<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx,
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx,
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="cashbac_biz">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>cashbac_biz</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>  
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace:

```
 if (kDebugMode) {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
} else {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
}
```

with:

```
if (!kIsWeb) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
  } else {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

Calling  `setCrashlytics()` will produce the error because Crashlytics is not supported on web.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by following the install directions [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview/), specifically these steps to add a build phase into XCode:

> 1. From Xcode select Runner from the project navigation.
> 2. Select the Build Phases tab, then click + > New Run Script Phase.
> 3. Add ${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run to the Type a script... text box.
> 4. Optionally you can also provide your app's built Info.plist location to the build phase's Input Files field: For example:
>    $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

Comment: The question mentions a crash on web. Instructions provided in this answer would only affect IOS.